# Retrieve value of rows column that is databound

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I've got a DataGrid that I've setup a doubleclick eventsetter that calls a method. Below is my xaml, following that is my codebehind page. The double click event works, but the return I get is "system.data.datarowview" and I don't know why. I'm trying to get the "vehicleID" value of the row which is its own column that is hidden.

XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name="OpenVehicles" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="False" SelectedItem="{Binding vehicleID}" SelectionUnit="FullRow">
<DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="OpenVehicleClick" />
    </Style>
</DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding vehicleID}" Width="*" Header="vehicleID" Visibility="Hidden"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding date, StringFormat=\{0:MMM dd yyyy \}}" Width="*" Header="Date"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding companyshortname}" Width="*" Header="Customer"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding subject}" Width="5*" Header="Vehicle Description"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FName}" Width="*" Header="Owner"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

C# Code:

```
        private void OpenVehicleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(OpenVehicles.CurrentCell.Item.ToString());
    }
```

Any ideas on how to retrieve the column value or any other suggestions are more than welcome. I'm beyond stumped.

Comment: This fixed it, for anybody else searching: (c# method)
DataRowView row = OpenVehicles.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
MessageBox.Show(row.Row["VehicleID"].ToString());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataRowView.Row` property will contain the `DataRow` that you want. From there you can access the column value using `DataRowView.Row["ColumnName"]` indexer

Comment: Thank you! This pushed me in the right direction. I was so close. Sorry I can't upvote you, not enough points or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

This bit in your XAML: `SelectedItem="{Binding vehicleID}"` means that the selected data item will be bound into the property `vehicleID` of the DataContext of the grid (which will be inherited from the control/page that it is on).

I notice that you've excluded any mention of a ItemsSource on the grid - the `vehicleID` property should be in the same class as the ItemSource property. You need to ensure that `vehicleID` is a public property, not a field - you cannot databind to a field. So, here is a couple of options depending on the way you've set things up:

```
pubic class MyPage
{
    public MyPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private void OpenVehicleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(VehicleID != null ? VehicleID.WhateverProperty : "Nothing selected");
    }

    public MyDataObject VehicleID { get; set; }
}
```

or, if you have a separate viewmodel assigned to the DataContext of the page/control:

```
private void OpenVehicleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedDataItem = ((MyViewModel) DataContext).VehicleID;
    MessageBox.Show(selectedDataItem != null ? selectedDataItem.WhateverProperty : "Nothing selected");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you're reffering to the grid itself.
Your event handles a row so use the event parameters to find what you need in the selected row (investigate them in debugging).